# How to correctly link MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql

So I'm writing a ticket support system and I'm relatively fresh to MYSQL so I was wondering what the best practice is for the database side.

I've worked out that I will probably need two tables, one of which contains a ticket, which would consist of multiple entries from ticket_messages

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tickets` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `messages` ?? ,
 `order_number` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `create_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ticket_messages` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `message` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `create_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

To link these properly, I assume I need to add the second tables ID's to the "messages" value of the first table. Is this best practice & how do I format the CREATE TABLE sql to accept multiple values in a single key?

Comment: The term you're looking for is called a "foreign key".  You are very much encouraged to take a look at some introductory MySQL tutorials to learn how to create tables and use foreign keys.  (Note: Your current understanding of foreign keys is backwards.  A single parent record doesn't contain references to many child records.  Instead, a single child record contains a reference to a single parent record.)

Comment: For multiple messages per ticket, there are a few ways to do it. You could have what I call a "pivot table", where you basically have two columns "tickets_id" and "ticket_messages_id" so you're linking each message to each ticket and you can remove the messages column in tickets. Or, just make an extra column in ticket messages "ticket_id", instead of the other way around.

Comment: If each ticket can have multiple messages, you probably want to add a "tickets_id" column to the ticket_messages table.  You can then use this to store the id of the relevant entry in the tickets table.  (And no need for the 'messages' column on your tickets table)

Comment: Appreciate all the responses. I better understand the connection being made through the tables now, thanks for the help!

Comment: Explain the purpose for each column (except `id`) in each table. Especially for `email` columns and `messages` column.